# VBA Use range with variable for columns and rows

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a range of table and paste it in a new workbook. I want to copy ranges composed of other columns and rows but as variable. For example, I copy columns C and E with the rows from 1 to 17, 20, from 32 to 39 and 45. And I want to proceed that maximum 10 times (for the columns) and if I finish selecting the columns to copy, I exit. To be more clear, there is an exampel: I select column B, D, F and than select the rows to be copied (they are the same for all the columns) and finally copy them and paste them in a new workbook. So I stoped after three times and copy what I selected and go out.

**My Code**

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim ColNum As Long
Dim col As String
Dim CopyRange As Range, row As String

For i = 1 To 10
    col = InputBox("Column number " & i & ", if finish write 'done'")
    Do While row <> "done"
        row = InputBox("row number to copy (max to 62), if finish write 'done'")
    Loop
    If col = "done" Then
        MsgBox ("copy finished")
        GoTo ExitIteration
    Else
        Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, Range(col & row, [col & row]))
    End If
Next

ExitIteration:

CopyRange.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Pedro.xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

Any help please solving it ?

Comment: At the moment you won't get past `Do While row <> "done"` because every time they input something other than "done", it will just loop back to the `InputBox` each time.

Comment: So what the solution to get my code working ?

Comment: Isn't this just a rehash of your previous question? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806057/vba-copy-selected-columns-and-rows-from-an-excel-table-and-convert-paste-it-in-a?noredirect=1#comment68833714_40806057

Comment: actually yes. But i'm trying to solve it but I didn't get any solution :(

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything inside your loop apart from waiting for "done" to be entered.

```
For i = 1 To 10
col = InputBox("Column number " & i & ", if finish write 'done'")
If col = "done" Then
    MsgBox ("copy finished")
    GoTo ExitIteration
Else
    Do While row <> "done"
        row = InputBox("row number to copy (max to 62), if finish write 'done'")
        Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, Range(col & row, [col & row]))
    Loop
End If
Next
```

Comment: i get always application-defined or object-defined error (error 1004)

Comment: this error comes in the step of //  Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, Range(col & row, [col & row]))

Answer (score 0):

I haven't time to write the code and make a example for my idea, sorry for that. But I will try to expose it...

Create a new sheet to feed your code with de initial/final columns and rows and compose a different ranges to accomplish your desire of proceed 10 maximum times. Use a three level loops to reach each one the cells that you need.